# How to store range/hash composite partitions in separate datafiles by range?

Tags: oracle, partitioning, database-partitioning

I'm creating a database which will utilize composite partitioning. I will partition one table using range partitioning (by date)
and then further subpartition it by hash (by client id). So far so good, no problem, but I also need to have those partitions
stored in separate data files each dbf holding data for a single month. I'm reading on composite partitions and what I found
is that primary range partitioning will be only a logical one and data will be stored in subpartitions instead which seems to
make my goal impossible. Am I right and should look for a different solution?

Thanks in advance.

My databases are Oracle 11g and Oracle 12

Comment: Are you sure you need to manage data files?  If you're using ASM it will take care of that for you.

Answer (score 1):

On existing table you can move partitions or subpartitions to a different tablespace, i.e. different datafile, examples:

```
ALTER TABLE scuba_gear MOVE SUBPARTITION bcd_types TABLESPACE tbs23; 
ALTER TABLE parts MOVE PARTITION depot2 TABLESPACE ts094;
```

see [Moving Subpartitions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-5ABF9E89-C1DD-41E6-BD87-6770A50B882F.htm) and [Moving Table Partitions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-793919DF-78AB-4B9D-874D-54C37D97F67F.htm)

For new tables typically you would be create them like this:

```
CREATE TABLE sales
  ( prod_id       NUMBER(6)
  , cust_id       NUMBER
  , time_id       DATE
  , channel_id    CHAR(1)
  , promo_id      NUMBER(6)
  , quantity_sold NUMBER(3)
  , amount_sold   NUMBER(10,2)
  )
 PARTITION BY RANGE (time_id) 
INTERVAL (NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1,'MONTH'))
STORE IN (ts_1, ts_2, ts_3, ts_4, ts_5, ts_6 ,ts_7 ,ts_8, ts_9, ts_10, ts_11, ts_12)
 SUBPARTITION BY HASH (cust_id) SUBPARTITIONS 4
 ( PARTITION before_2000 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-JAN-2000','dd-MON-yyyy')));
```

Oracle then will put the monthly partitions by "round-robin" method to these 12 tablespaces. `STORE IN` clause is also possible for subpartitions, see [Creating a composite range-hash partitioned table](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16541/part_admin001.htm#sthref265)